# linq projection element count

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose:

```
var a = SomeCollection.OrderBy(...)
              .Select(f => new MyType
                               {
                                  counter = ? //I want counter value, so what first
                                              //object have counter=1, second counter=2 
                                              //and so on
                                  a=f.sometthing,
                                  ...
                                });
```

How do I set this counter value? Or do I fave to iterate `a` afterwards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the overload of [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) that gives you the current element's 0-based index.

```
.Select((item, index) => new MyType
            { 
                counter = index + 1,
                a = item.Something
```

Comment: This overload is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx

Comment: @ren, if using EF, you would materialize the collection from the database and then you could use this approach. ie., `theEFQuery.AsEnumerable().Select((item, index) =>`. The call `AsEnumerable()` evaluates the query at the database, and the code that follows runs in memory. If you want to get the actual row numbers inside the database itself, this still does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

Simply capture a variable:

```
int index = 1;

var a = SomeCollection.OrderBy(...)
        .Select(x => new MyType { counter = index++; });
```

The counter will increment as each iteration is called.